# Backing up Nebula Studio Draft Schema with its drag and drop features

Tags: nebula-graph

I have a Nebula studio instance running on its default port of 7001. I have a Draft Schema that several of us are editing and we have already managed to accidentally overwrite /lose changes.

I can see there is a directory called: /usr/local/nebula-graph-studio/ and have backed up the file tasks.db. I am hoping that periodically backing this up might mitigate issues but would like to confirm this and also whether there a way to specifically duplicate the only draft schema we are all sharing along with its drag and drop feature ?